# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound' Error

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, playsound

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'. Getting this error. I dont know whats the issue. I am using two laptop on one there is Intel i5 processor and on another there is ryzen 5 and I am facing issue with ryzen 5 laptop and on both the laptop I installed the saftware the same way. Do processsor makes any difference. Or there is some other issue. Can anybody help?

Comment: Some details/background/code samples would help. Maybe [googleing](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=No+module+named+%27playsound%27.&ia=web) helps?

Comment: So, you installed it as per the [official instructions](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/)? Did you verify that you installed it to the same environment that you're running scripts in? Your hardware has **nothing** at all to do with this issue, by the way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RobertLujo I tried all of em. But didnt work.

Comment: @RandomDavis How to verify that. I am Totally new to this. while you'll reply i am googling that.

Comment: @RandomDavis I checked the path in settings C:\Users\Shashank Sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\  and  C:\Users\Shashank Sagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin are in the path in environment variables